# Add input if the last input is filled

Tags: javascript, input

I have a HMTL page with input (type text) created by Javascript,
i have to create a function where if the last input is filled will be created another input.
And if this last input created is filled, create another one and again.
How can i do this?

This is my code until now:

```
function visualizzaModifica(array, div)
{
    div.html("");
    div.append("<br>");

    let i=1;

    array.forEach(function (e)
    {
        div.append
        (
            "<div class='input-group'>"+
            "<input type='text' id='inputModificaNome"+i+"' class='form-control' value='"+e.nominativo+"'>"+
            "<input type='text' id='inputModificaCellulare"+i+"' class='form-control' value='"+e.cellulare+"'>"+
            "</div>"
        );

        i++;
    });

    div.append("<br>");
    div.append("<button id='btnSalvaTeamLeaderProduzione' class='btn btn-secondary'>Salva</button>");
}
```

between the forEach and the button Salva i have to insert the function that insert input again and again, if you see something wrong or something that could be better in this function tell me. Thank you

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok! now i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create another text field if the newly created text box is filled, you need a event handler to achieve that. Which means the we need to assign event handler to the newly created text field as well. Demonstrate below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  createNext(0);
});


function createNext(index) {

  if ($('#input-' + index).length == 0) {
    // create the next text box if not exists
    var next = $('<input>', {
      id: 'input-' + index,
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'text ' + index,
      class: 'text-chain'
    });

    next.on('change', function() {
      createNext(index + 1)
    });
    next.appendTo($('body'));
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excuse me and if i have a button that must be always under the last input? how can i do?
(with input in column)

Comment: Many ways. You can wrap the text field with another <div> and put the button next to the <div>. Making the <div> the boundary of all text field allow you to keep using .appendTo(). Of course you need to change the target to the new <div> instead of <body>. If changing the html structure is not an option, you can use .after() w.r.t. the last text field, or .before() w.r.t. the button. Check the jQuery api http://api.jquery.com/ Dom Insertion section. API is always your friend!